# What type of password encryption is this?

Tags: php, zend-framework, hash

What type of encryption is this? I tried the md5 and hash on this but didn't work. I don't have contact on the person who made this.
Here is the code

```
2706b378a10dedb9c98b4c272197b6edcdb7a583
```

Comment: Question is: why do you want to know?

Comment: The value of that is **p@ssw0rd**. I wanna know cause in my code I tried changing it to md5 but still reads that encryption type.

Comment: It's best to just check in source code which checks this password. People use sometimes strange ideas like hashing it with MD5, and then with SHA or split and then hash parts and then whole again. Are you sure there are no salt also with this password?

Answer (score 3):

At 40 digits, it's probably a SHA-1 hash. But realistically, there's no way to *know*.

Potential alternatives: ripemd160 tiger160,3 tiger160,4 haval160,3 haval160,4 haval160,5

That's all of the common-ish 40-digit hashes that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

It's 40 bytes of hexadecimal, it is likely a sha1 hash.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php